# Add text to Title dynamically using tags

Tags: tags

I am trying to add custom text to title according to the tag selected.

For example:

If I've added a tag named 'Private', The title should look like "Page Title From title field + custom text assigned to the tag 'Private'".

i.e. "Iron Man - Review - Awesome"

here awesome will be the custom text assigned to the tag private.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below assumes that only one tag ( 'private' ) has a text associated with it:

```
function add_tag_text_to_title( $title, $id = null ) {
    if ( has_tag( 'private' ) ) { 
        return $title . ' - Awesome';
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_tag_text_to_title', 10, 2 );
```

If you have more than one tag with text associated with it:

```
function add_tag_texts_to_title( $title, $id = null ) {
    $tag_texts = array (
        'tag1' => 'text1',
        'tag2' => 'text2',
        'tag3' => 'text3'
    );
    $new_title = $title;
    foreach ( $tag_texts as $key => $value ) {
        if ( has_tag( $key ) ) 
            $new_title .= ' - ' . $value;
    }
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_tag_texts_to_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you, Frank.
I'm very new to this and it would be great if you could tell me where I've to add this.

Comment: Add it to your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: The first one gave me error, so tried the second code. It worked. Thank alot. :)

Comment: I've edited the first example where in line 2 ')' was missing. Now it will work.

Comment: Ran into a problem. Please check the titles of menu bar items here: http://www.shortofthemonth.com/film/jasmine/

Comment: Hi Frank, I've removed the code from the site for now.
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/TSRpZfA.png